# Generate temporary string files on gradle build

Tags: android, gradle

I created a gradle task, which can generate some "res/values*/extrastring.xml" Files.

Everytime I build the project now, these files get generated.
I want to use this strings (via R.string.*) in the project. But I do not want them in my module to appear. It would be nice, when they go into one of the "gen" folders.

How could I achive this?

Comment: What should happen to these files once they are generated? Do you want them to be part of some archive, do you want them to be published anywhere, etc? I.e. what do you mean by "recognized"?

Comment: sorry, is that description better?